# Language for REST API

Tags: rest, api

I just wanted to know what **PROS** and **CONS** are there when reading REST APIs using Javascript, Pyhton,... what language do you **recomend** for this task?

I've tried with Python 3.4 but I don't think it is the best decission. I've also tried with Postman but I didn't succeed and I don't want to use google tools.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question for pros and cons has been already answered by different person in [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23386/pros-and-cons-of-restful-architecture).

Basically an application will have front-end and back-end app. All the data logic will go to back-end service and all the view logic (optionally, with some data logic as well, based on project.) will go to front-end service. Front-end applications basically needs data to show to the users which it gets from back-end service (aka api). This communication between front-end and back-end needs to follow same protocol. REST and SOAP are two most popular protocols but I recommend you REST.

Now there are many more REST frameworks like, Ruby on Rails, Django that helps you build back-end service following REST protocol. And then there comes front-end app. Basically, javascript frameworks like angular, react are mostly used to build front-end app. It has advantages over manipulating JSON object response from REST web service (REST api).

Postman is a tool that helps you test REST api's. If you have api-endpoint (like, https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1) and method (like, GET) then you can use postman to GET response from that api.

Front end application adds logic to these response and helps user to visualize the data.

And at last, don't hesitate to google. Because it's all about googling-stackoverflow.